# Why he didn't use "to do" in this question: "What exactly did your Uncle say I was going to be doing?"

Tags: grammar

I'm confused about the grammar in this sentence.

Comment: *To do* is an activity, I'm going to eat pie. *To be doing* is that, too, but also shows a schedule of activities, I'm going to be eating pie. So my schedule will be too busy with those activities to teach you to bake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In everyday English, it is perfectly acceptable to say "I was going to do" or "I was going to be doing."

The main difference is that "to do" implies the action is brief, while "to be doing" implies the action is continuous. The first is called the "perfect" case, while the second is called "perfect progressive."

Let's change the verb to demonstrate this.

Example:

"What exactly did your uncle say I was going to *eat* tomorrow?"
**In this example, you will only be eating once.**

"What exactly did your uncle say I was going to *be eating* this weekend?"

**In this example, you will be eating continuously**

Answer (score 0):

Shifting from "to do" to "to be doing" shifts your description from being a description of an action to being a description of a state.

All of the rest of my answer is based at least in part in interpretation of connotation, which is not entirely objective.

"Going to do" connotes you are going to be doing the activity soon or immediately. "Going to be doing" has a connotation of referring to what you will be doing at a later time.

Based on the above interpretation of connotations:
In this particular example, because the uncle "said" (past tense) that you were "going to be doing" (future tense, interpreted to be in the non-immediate future), and to "be doing" is a state, the person who is being asked the question was likely expected to be in the state of doing the activity as the question is being asked. Since going to do is a description of an action (connoted to happen promptly), at the moment the person is being asked they are not expected to be doing the action simultaneously.